# Div unable to cover expected area

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am making a web-app in Nextjs with Tailwind and am trying to get all pages.tsx to cover all space between header and footer.

The footer and header are supposed to stay at top and bottom, which they do, but I am left with unusable space. The border are used to visualise the area occupied, but it only occupies to fit content (in all the page.tsx files), while the border of children div in root layout.tsx goes around the whole page (except header and footer).

I have tried flex-grow in the containers, min-h-full, h-full, but to no avail.
For info, using min-h-screen works, but this makes 'main' page use 100%, and pushes total height to over 100vh.

This is my current layout.tsx:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={poppins.className}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          minHeight: "100vh",
        }}
      >
        <Header />
        <div className="flex-grow border-2 border-white">{children}</div>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And this is the root page.tsx (same effect on all other page.tsx):

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="m-5 border-2 border-white">
      <p>Hello and welcome</p>

      <div className="bottom-0">
        <button>b1</button>
        <button>b2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT:

I am still not sure why this problem occurred, but I fixed it by making 'children div' relative;

```
return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={poppins.className}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          minHeight: "100vh",
        }}
      >
        <Header />
        <div id="children" className="flex-grow relative">
          {children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
```

and giving all the pages' parent divs `id="container"`, and using this css:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

min-width as min-height was necessary for mine to work, if anyone else is stumbling upon the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example through a service like [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/)? I tried to recreate the issue you're seeing in this [Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wEJih7XQGM) but it seems to be working as expected.